# transform: translate()

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему после оператора присваивания, функция `translate()`, в кавычках и аргумент тоже?
`count` это число.

`sliderLine.style.transform = 'translate(-'+ count * width + 'px)';`

Не могу понять эту строку кода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Все свойства, которые задаются через `style`, должны быть строками, или верно приводящимися к строке, как например число `0.5` для `opacity`.

Если написать `translate( count * width + px )`, то будет ошибка. Потому что функции `translate` в JS не существует, а переменная `px` тоже не задана.

Сделать это рабочим можно так (но это никому не нужно и бред, просто пример для понимания):

```
let translate = val => `translate(${val})`; // функция, которая делает строку
let px = 'px'; // просто переменная со строкой 'px'
sliderLine.style.transform = translate( count * width + px );
```

То есть функция всё равно в итоге просто сделает строку.

Comment: решил ради интереса затестить - что-то не работает Ваша функция let translate = val => `translate:(${val})`;

Comment: @humster_spb вот скрин проверки в консоли - https://i.vgy.me/R41ReG.png

Comment: не знаю, что там у Вас за проверка в консоли - вот я попытался сделать воспроизводимый пример, не работает - https://jsfiddle.net/m5y7htef/

Comment: @humster_spb двоеточие в строке лишнее было. Функция тем не менее работает :) . поправил, спасибо

Comment: а, ну да, точно - двоеточие-то я и не заметил :)))

Answer (score 3):

Здесь происходит вычисление значения и конкатенация строк:

1. 'translate(-'  это первая строка
2. count * width - выражение
3. 'px)' - вторая строка

И все это склеивается с помощью плюсов